# Why is my hidden_field being ignored? Not passing parameter

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, hidden-field

I am trying to toggle a subscribe btn back and forth using Ajax But the hidden field isnt doing anything at all. I've tried setting a , value: 4 or wrapping the form in escape_js but still doesn't even show up.

relationship/destroy.js.erb:

```
$("#unfollow_<%=@user.id%>").replaceWith('<div id="follow_<%=@user.id%>"><%=
form_for(current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @user.id), remote: true) do |f|
f.hidden_field :followed_id
f.submit "Subscribe"
end
%></div>')
```

logs:

```
Started POST "/relationships" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-21 05:38:46 -0400
Processing by RelationshipsController#create as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Jx9SG25KLJH5UfstrOw3RudtgqJtKwidvT4xGt+bqas=", "commit"=>"Subscribe ∞"}
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '1gPcW8-7ey4aSGV-g1O_lw' LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
app/controllers/relationships_controller.rb:6:in `create'
```

The POST is missing this parameter (the input is missing in the html as well):

```
"relationship"=>{"followed_id"=>"46"}
<input id="relationship_followed_id" name="relationship[followed_id]" type="hidden" value="92" />
```

When I try:

```
f.hidden_field followed_id: @user.id
```

I get undefined method `{:followed_id=>2}' for #

RelationshipController for kicks:

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
  current_user.follow!(@user)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.js
  end
end

def destroy
  @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
  current_user.unfollow!(@user)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.js
  end
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [hidden\_field is being ignored?? NoMethodError (undefined method \`\[\]' for nil:NilClass)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231571/hidden-field-is-being-ignored-nomethoderror-undefined-method-for-nilnil)

Comment: Do yourself a favor and put the html in a partial and render that partial in your javascript file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alternative

save it as _partial_form.html.erb

```
  <div id="follow_<%=@user.id%>">
    <%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @user.id), remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %>
    <%= f.submit "Subscribe" %>
    <%= end %>
  </div>
```

in your js.erb

```
  $(selector).replaceWith('<%= j render 'path to your partial_form'%>')
```

and make sure your followed_id has value, to make test value,

```
<%= f.hidden_field :followed_id, :value => 18 %>
```

Comment: What was different about this approach? Was it just a syntax issue in the JS file? I thought I tried the partial approach before